# My conjecture $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{H^s_{n,s}\over 2^n{n}}=\eta(s+1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I saw these two formulas on some sites

(1)

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{1\over 2^n{n}}=\eta(1)$$

(2)

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{H_n\over 2^n{n}}=\eta(2)$$

Then I generalised below base on a hunch

Let $H_{n,s}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{1\over n^s}$ and $H_{n,0}=1$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{H^s_{n,s}\over 2^n{n}}=\eta(s+1)$$

I haven't got any idea on how to star proving this formula, any hints that may help me?

(1) can shown below by changing

$$\ln(2)=1-{1\over 2}+{1\over 3}-{1\over 4}+\cdots$$

into

$$\ln(2)={1\over2}+{1\over 2^2}\left(1-{1\over 2}\right)+{1\over 2^3}\left(1-{2\over 2}+{1\over 3}\right)+{1\over 2^4}\left(1-{3\over 2}+{3\over 3}-{1\over 4}\right)+\cdots$$

$$\ln(2)={1\over 2\cdot1}+{1\over 2^2\cdot 2}+{1\over 2^3\cdot 3}+{1\over 2^4\cdot4}+\cdots$$

Comment: What does $\eta$ indicate?

Comment: $\eta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^{n-1}\over n^s}$

Comment: Just a suggestion: the standard notation for $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^s}$ is $H_n^{(s)}$.

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake : it is the [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) $\eta(s) = (1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)$

Comment: @user1952009 Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the assumption $x\in(-1,1)$, if we start from:
$$ -\log(1-x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n}{n} \tag{1}$$
we get:
$$ -\frac{\log(1-x)}{1-x} = \sum_{n\geq 1} H_n x^n \tag{2} $$
and by integrating both sides:
$$ \frac{1}{2}\log(1-x)^2 = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{H_n}{n+1}\,x^{n+1} \tag{3} $$
so:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{H_{n+1}}{n+1}x^{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}\log(1-x)^2+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}$$
and:

> $$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{H_n}{n}x^n = \frac{1}{2}\log(1-x)^2+\text{Li}_2(x)\tag{4}$$

Then your $(1)$ follows from my $(1)$ evaluated at $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and your $(2)$ follows from my $(4)$ evaluated at $x=\frac{1}{2}$ through the dilogarithm reflection formula. Now you may try to follow the same steps by replacing $-\log(1-x)$ in my $(1)$ by $\text{Li}_k(x)$. Anyway,

$$ 0.82799\ldots=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{{H_n^{(2)}}^2}{n\,2^n}\neq \eta(3) = \frac{3}{4}\zeta(3)=0.901543\ldots $$